# What does a forward slash before a pipe in cmd do to remove the line ending of an echo?

Tags: cmd, echo, pipe, carriage-return

This code:

```
    @echo off
    echo/|set /p ="Executing backup...."
    echo/|set /p =" backup procedure"
```

... came from [Echoing in the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097041/echoing-in-the-same-line) and produces the below output in a cmd window:

```
    Executing backup....backup procedure
```

However, I cant seem to find an explanation through google on what the forward slash does to the `¿pipe?` to cause `set`'s output to be `echo`*ed* to the `console / stdout`

If anyone could also suggest a good website for learning more about `cmd` / `cmd` programs' features like this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: `echo` prints the result of `set /p =...` with or without the `/` before the pipe, so I'm not sure what your question is asking.

Comment: (It will also print `set /p =...` with random junk after the `echo`, too, since it's reading the piped stuff and not the arguments it receives.)

Comment: @tenterhook Thanks. So it does. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No problem, the question was interesting enough for me to try running the commands ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Care of https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201210/tenterhook

1) echo prints the result of set /p =... with or without the / before the pipe, so I'm not sure what your question is asking

2) (It will also print set /p =... with random junk after the echo, too, since it's reading the piped stuff and not the arguments it receives.)

I will hence suggest edits to the referenced SO post, to prevent others confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The `echo/` is simply a way of printing only an empty line, instead of `ECHO IS ON` for a single `echo`.

But in this case it's completly unimportant, as the only use of the echo is for creating some stuff for the pipe, so the set /p will not wait for user input.

But this way to echo text without a linefeed is very inefficient, as a pipe creates two new instances of cmd.exe.
It's much simpler and faster to use

```
<nul set /p "=My Text"
```

The redirect from `NUL` will also stop the waiting for user input.