# Loading progress animation like with batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

i want to make such as loading indicator just like : installation is running...
and those dots should be appear progressively and once they are three their number should be reinitialized to one dot and all happens in the same line.

for this i've tried to mix code of two small scripts : [the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368041/how-to-code-a-spinner-for-waiting-processes-in-a-batch-file/368865#368865) plays continuestly the dots
and [the seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097041/echoing-in-the-same-line/4097156#4097156) makes a counter increase its value by echoing it in the same line.

at the end i got this code which is the closest solution for what i want to achieve but still with a problem which is that when there are already three dots, the next row which has less number of dots will overwrite its similar part from the previous one but the remaining part from the previous row will stay so at the end it looks like there are always three dots and all will looks like just a simple static echoed text..

here is the code :

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions


call :CreateCR
:spinner
set mSpinner=%mSpinner%.

if %mSpinner%'==.................................' (
    set mSpinner=.


)       
        :: Wait one second.
        ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 >nul

        set /P "=Installation Java en cours%mSpinner%!CR!" <nul


::set /p "=Installation Java en cours" <nul
::echo %mSpinner%

goto spinner


:exit
::echo(
goto :eof

:CreateCR
rem setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
set "X=."
for /L %%c in (1,1,13) DO set X=!X:~0,4094!!X:~0,4094!

echo !X!  > %temp%\cr.tmp
echo\>> %temp%\cr.tmp
for /f "tokens=2 usebackq" %%a in ("%temp%\cr.tmp") do (
   endlocal
   set cr=%%a
   goto :eof
)
goto :eof
```

Comment: just a site note, when you run commands which print percentage the console "ConEmu" will actually make a graphical progress bar out of it.https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Progress

Comment: I believe it can be done, but I'd refer you to this link https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt/category/87960-cmd with specific reference to the suggestions about adding `spinner` and `ecko` to W10...

Answer (score 0):

You can capture a backspace character to a variable like this ([courtesy of dbenham](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2124&mobile=on)):

```
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
```

Then to erase your dots, simply send a number of

```
<NUL set /P "=%BS%"
```

... one `%BS%` for each dot you want to erase.  As an alternative, you could use a spinner that spins instead of dots that grow.  [See this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368041/).  In the answer there, insert the `for /f` line above to capture the backspace to `%BS%` at the top of the script, and replace all occurrences of `^H` with `%BS%` in the spinner strings at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i ll try it, just your last link is refering to this same question. Please give me the right one :)

Comment: @Bardelman Sorry about that.  Edited and fixed.  Just in case you don't know, that `<NUL set /P "=string"` simulates `echo -n` in other OSes.  It writes to stdout without sending a line break.  So if you want to send single dots, just `<NUL set /P "=."`, then wait, then send another `<NUL set /P "=."`, and repeat until you want no more dots.  They'll all appear on the same line.  Then `<NUL set /P "=%BS%%BS%%BS%"` to erase three dots and start over.  See how that works?

Comment: i made this change in the if statement : if %mSpinner%'==.....' (
 
 set mSpinner=.
 
 for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a" > nul
 <NUL set /P "=%BS%%BS%%BS%%BS%" 
 
) but even it works i got this error '"C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\IEUpdate\AdapterTroubleshooter
.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or an external command each time the if code is executed so that the next line should be echoed   after that error message.  Actually, i forgot to mention that i'm running my code in a windows 7 machine. –

Answer (score 0):

A more simplistic approach would be the following:

```
@echo off
:spinner
set mSpinner=%mSpinner%.
if %mSpinner%'==....' (set mSpinner=.)
cls
echo Installation in progress%mSpinner%
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 >nul
goto spinner
```